# offsetLeft issue with Chrome when using relative position

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I seem to see a problem when running offsetLeft measurements on Chrome. On firefox the measurement seems fine. offsetTop is fine.

With the following HTML:

```
<div id="theAbsoluteParent">
    hello <span id="theRelativeChild">world <span id="theMeasure">!</span></span>
</div>
```

with this as CSS:

```
#theAbsoluteParent
{
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    left:100px;
    width:300px;
}

#theRelativeChild
{
    position:relative;
    top:50px
}
```

then running the following code:

```
document.getElementById('theMeasure').theMeasure.offsetLeft
```

from the numbers i get, it seems like offsetLeft is not getting the relative position to its parent - theRelativeChild. rather it returns what seems like the position relative to theAbsoluteParent. this is not the case with offsetTop.

When running on firefox, the problem is gone.

Is there a way around this? i want theMeasure relative position to theAbsoluteParent. figured i'll just have a loop iterating offsetParents and adding...but with this bug it doesn't work, obviously.

Got a JSFiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/galkahana/UG4Vn/ - to demonstrate the issue.